# Getting an IDLError when I try to create a vector of a defined Struct

Tags: instructions, frontend, vec

I currently have defined a Ship struct in my backend code, as well as a Port struct which contains an attribute ships_berthed that is of type Vec.

However, on my frontend (Svelte), when I try to call on the aforementioned vector, I receive an error that goes:
IdlError: Type not found: {"type":{"defined":"Ship"}}

I am assuming this is from my .ts file in my types folder but I am unsure how to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :))

Answer (score 1):

I also having the same issue then i came across this thread. The mistake was silly/funny.

I had this

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone)]
struct Friend {
    address: Pubkey,
    friend_at: i64,
    last_meet: i64
}

#[account]
pub struct User {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
    friends: Vec<Friend>,
    school: String
}
```

Then is changed it to this

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Friend {
    address: Pubkey,
    friend_at: i64,
    last_meet: i64
}

#[account]
pub struct User {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
    friends: Vec<Friend>,
    school: String
}
```

Yeah just forget to add `pub` keyword in front of Friend struct. Your problem could be something else but this was the case for me. Thank You.